# Создание b2ContactListener

Tags: c++, box2d

У меня есть class CONTACT_LISTENER : public b2ContactListener{...}, и класс игрока и мяча.
Проблема заключается в том, что ContactListener не обнаруживает контакт двух тел (в каждой функции ContactListener я поставил вывод сообщений, и ни одно сообщение не выводилось). Хотя я запускал обычный цикл вне класса ContactListener и контакт находился. Мне кажется, что проблема состоит в SetContactListener, или как по сути активировать ContactListener. В статье я нашел следующие строки и использую их:

```
CONTACT_LISTENER contact_listener_instance;
World.SetContactListener(&contact_listener_instance);
```

Классы персонажа и мяча:

```
class PLAYER
{
public:
    Texture texture_player_move;
    Sprite sprite_player_move;
    b2BodyDef body_def;
    b2PolygonShape player_shape;
    b2Body *body;
    b2FixtureDef body_fixture;
    PLAYER* player_data = this;
 
    bool canHit = false;
 
    PLAYER(String path, int X_rect, int Y_rect, int W_rect, int H_rect,  float X_pos, float Y_pos)
    {
        std::cout << "player ready";
        texture_player_move.loadFromFile(path);
        texture_player_move.setSmooth(true);
        sprite_player_move.setTexture(texture_player_move);
        sprite_player_move.setOrigin(135, 240);
        sprite_player_move.setTextureRect(IntRect(X_rect, Y_rect, W_rect, H_rect));
 
        body_def.type = b2_dynamicBody;
        body_def.position.Set(X_pos, Y_pos);
        player_shape.SetAsBox(60 / SCALE, 160 / SCALE);
        body = World.CreateBody(&body_def);
 
        body_fixture.shape = &player_shape;
        body_fixture.filter.categoryBits = 0xFFFF; // 0x0004
        body_fixture.filter.maskBits = 0xFFFF; // 0x0002 | 0x0008
        body_fixture.density = 1;
        body->CreateFixture(&body_fixture);
        body->SetFixedRotation(true);
        body->SetUserData(this);
    }
};
 
 
class BALL
{
public:
    Texture texture_ball;
    Sprite sprite_ball;
    b2BodyDef body_def;
    b2CircleShape ball_shape;
    b2Body* ball;
    b2FixtureDef ball_fixture;
    BALL* ball_data = this;
    BALL()
    {
        texture_ball.loadFromFile("C://Users/1/source/repos/Game Volley/Game Volley/images/ball.png");
        texture_ball.setSmooth(true);
        sprite_ball.setTexture(texture_ball);
        sprite_ball.setOrigin(32, 32);
 
        body_def.type = b2_dynamicBody;
        body_def.position.Set(10, -5);
        ball_shape.m_radius = 32 / SCALE;
        ball = World.CreateBody(&body_def);
 
        ball_fixture.shape = &ball_shape;
        ball_fixture.filter.categoryBits = 0xFFFF; //0x0008
        ball_fixture.filter.maskBits = 0xFFFF; //0x0002
        ball_fixture.restitution = 0.75;
        ball_fixture.density = 0.2;
        ball->CreateFixture(&ball_fixture);
        ball->SetUserData(this);
    }
};
```

ContactListener:

```
class CONTACT_LISTENER : public b2ContactListener
{
    void BeginContact(b2Contact* contact)
    {
        std::cout << "beginContact";
    }
 
    void EndContact(b2Contact* contact)
    {
        std::cout << "endContact";
    }
 
    void PreSolve(b2Contact* contact, b2Manifold* oldManifold)
    {
        std::cout << "preSolve";
        if (contact->GetFixtureA()->GetBody() == Player_1.body && contact->GetFixtureB()->GetBody() == Ball.ball
            || contact->GetFixtureA()->GetBody() == Ball.ball && contact->GetFixtureB()->GetBody() == Player_1.body)
        {
            if (Player_1.canHit and onGround) {
                std::cout << "preSolve";
                //меняем направление
                float ball_x = Ball.ball->GetPosition().x; // нахожу позицию мяча по X
                float Distance = (1920 / 2) - (ball_x * SCALE); //Окно 1920x1080, делю на 2 - нахожу центр, перевожу в метры и отнимаю позицию мяча по X.
                float Height = 250; //высота моей сетки 250 пикселей, делю, перевожу в метры
                float Time = Height / 9.81; //Рассчет времени
                Ball.ball->SetLinearVelocity(b2Vec2(Distance / Time, Time)); //Изменение скорости мяча
            }
            contact->SetEnabled(false);
        }
    }
 
    void PostSolve(b2Contact* contact, b2ContactImpulse* impulse)
    {
        std::cout << "postSolve";
    }
};
```

Буду рад помощи! Заранее спасибо!

Comment: В приведенном коде CONTACT_LISTENER нигде не используется...

Comment: он должен вызываться при контакте двух тел